# Como fazer uma aplicação do Delphi executar como administrador?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe3, delphi-xe5, delphi-xe6, delphi-xe4

Eu estou usando o Delphi XE4 e não tenho ideia de como fazer com que uma aplicação peça permissão administrativa ao Windows 7 para executar, procurei em sites e bolgs, mas não encontrei a resposta! Me ajude por favor!

Comment: É necessário utilizar um manifesto, mais informações em [Delphi and Windows Vista User Account Control](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/33942).

Answer (score 6):

Primeiro você deve criar um arquivo de texto com o seguinte conteúdo:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">
  <assemblyIdentity type="win32" name="Teste" version="3.1.0.0" processorArchitecture="*"/>
  <dependency>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity type="win32" name="Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls" version="6.0.0.0" publicKeyToken="6595b64144ccf1df" language="*" processorArchitecture="*"/>
    </dependentAssembly>
  </dependency>
  <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
    <security>
      <requestedPrivileges>
        <requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false"/>
        </requestedPrivileges>
    </security>
  </trustInfo>
  <compatibility xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:compatibility.v1">
    <application>
      <!--The ID below indicates application support for Windows Vista -->
      <supportedOS Id="{e2011457-1546-43c5-a5fe-008deee3d3f0}"/>
      <!--The ID below indicates application support for Windows 7 -->
      <supportedOS Id="{35138b9a-5d96-4fbd-8e2d-a2440225f93a}"/>
      <!--Windows 8 Support -->
      <supportedOS Id="{4a2f28e3-53b9-4441-ba9c-d69d4a4a6e38}"/>
    </application>
  </compatibility>
</assembly>
```

Salve com o nome "Manifest.manifest", dentro da pasta do seu projeto (recomendo que crie uma subpasta chamada "Resources", para colocar esses arquivos).

Depois disso crie outro arquivo de texto, com o seguinte conteúdo:

```
1 24 "Manifest.manifest"
```

Salve este outro arquivo com o nome Manifest.rc, na mesma pasta onde salvou o arquivo "Manifest.manifest" acima.

Então depois disso compile este arquivo usando a seguinte linha de comando (ou crie um BAT para isso):

```
BRCC32.exe Manifest.rc
```

Será criado automaticamente um arquivo chamado Manifest.res

Então, por último, adicione a seguinte linha no seu código:

```
{$R 'Manifest.res'}
```

Desta forma, ao abrir o executável, se o UAC do Windows estiver ativado, será requerida a elevação dos privilégios.

Espero ter ajudado! Boa sorte!

Answer (score 3):

Para fazer isso você vai precisar criar um arquivo de *Manifest* customizado.

> **Dica:** Para saber mais sobre arquivo de *Manifest* customizado você pode dar
>   uma olhada nesse link da *Embarcadero*: [Customizing the Windows
>   Application Manifest
>   File](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Customizing_the_Windows_Application_Manifest_File)

---

**VOCÊ PODE USAR ESSE ARQUIVO AQUI**

Se preferir pode usar esse aquivo pronto, basta fazer o seguinte:

1. Crie um arquivo de texto e cole o conteúdo abaixo
2. Salve na pasta do seu projeto com o nome que preferir, desde que tenha a extensão ***.manifest***, o mais comum é que o arquivo tenha o nome ***Manifest.manifest***

**Conteúdo do arquivo de *manifest***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">
  <assemblyIdentity type="win32" name="Teste" version="3.1.0.0" processorArchitecture="*"/>
  <dependency>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity type="win32" name="Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls" version="6.0.0.0" publicKeyToken="6595b64144ccf1df" language="*" processorArchitecture="*"/>
    </dependentAssembly>
  </dependency>
  <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
    <security>
      <requestedPrivileges>
        <requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false"/>
        </requestedPrivileges>
    </security>
  </trustInfo>
  <compatibility xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:compatibility.v1">
    <application>
      <!--The ID below indicates application support for Windows Vista -->
      <supportedOS Id="{e2011457-1546-43c5-a5fe-008deee3d3f0}"/>
      <!--The ID below indicates application support for Windows 7 -->
      <supportedOS Id="{35138b9a-5d96-4fbd-8e2d-a2440225f93a}"/>
      <!--Windows 8 Support -->
      <supportedOS Id="{4a2f28e3-53b9-4441-ba9c-d69d4a4a6e38}"/>
    </application>
  </compatibility>
</assembly>
```

**USANDO O *MANIFEST* NO SEU PROJETO**

Siga os passos abaixo:

1. Clique no menu *Project*
2. Clique na opção *Options*
3. Na janela que abrirá selecione *Application*
4. No *GroupBox* *Runtime Themes* clique no *ComboBox* e selecione a opção *Use custom manifest*
5. O campo *Custom Manifest* que fica abaixo do *ComboBox* será habilitado, clique no botão com os três pontinhos para selecionar o arquivo de *manifest* customizado que você preparou
6. Compile seu projeto e o executável já contará com a solicitação de elevação, você pode verificar isso rodando o executável ou ainda observando que o ícone da sua aplicação agora tem aquele escudo na frente.

> **IMPORTANTE:** Com o *Manifest* você deve perceber que ao pressionar **F9** para rodar sua aplicação em modo *debug* o Delphi não conseguirá executar sua aplicação, a solução para isso é fechar a IDE do Delphi e abri-la
>   novamente com a opção ***Executar como administrador***

**IMAGENS QUE ILUSTRAM OS PASSOS QUE INDIQUEI**

Passos 1 ao 4

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Passo 5

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Passo 6

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score -1):

Acrescentei versões do windows no XML, caso alguém precise:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">
  <assemblyIdentity type="win32" name="NOME DO APLICATIVO COM A EXTESÃO (.EXE)" version="3.1.0.0" processorArchitecture="*"/>
  <dependency>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity type="win32" name="Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls" version="6.0.0.0" publicKeyToken="6595b64144ccf1df" language="*" processorArchitecture="*"/>
    </dependentAssembly>
  </dependency>
  <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
    <security>
      <requestedPrivileges>
        <requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false"/>
        </requestedPrivileges>
    </security>
  </trustInfo>
  <compatibility xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:compatibility.v1">
    <application>
      <!--Windows Vista/6.0/Server 2008-->
      <supportedOS Id="{e2011457-1546-43c5-a5fe-008deee3d3f0}"/>
      <!--Windows 7/6.1/Server 2008 R2-->
      <supportedOS Id="{35138b9a-5d96-4fbd-8e2d-a2440225f93a}"/>
      <!--Windows 8/6.2/Server 2012-->
      <supportedOS Id="{4a2f28e3-53b9-4441-ba9c-d69d4a4a6e38}"/>
      <!--Windows 8.1/6.3/Server 2012 R2-->            
      <supportedOS Id="{1f676c76-80e1-4239-95bb-83d0f6d0da78}"/>
      <!--Windows 10/10.*-->            
      <supportedOS Id="{8e0f7a12-bfb3-4fe8-b9a5-48fd50a15a9a}"/>
    </application>
  </compatibility>   
</assembly>
```